# How do i get the ID of ApplicantRatingScore??? (Yii2)

Tags: javascript, php, yii2

I have this controller and I need to retrieve the ApplicantRatingScore ID but nothing is working!!! When i input $model->id, it gets the id of the table Applicant. The controller name is called ApplicantController.php

```
public function actionRate2($id)
    {   
        $model = new ApplicantRatingScore();
        $modell = $this->findModel($id);
        
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) { 
            $id = $model->id;
            
            //Yii::$app->db->createCommand('INSERT INTO ebs_applicant_rating_score(applicant_id) VALUES ('. $modell->id.');')->execute();
            
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $modell->id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('rating2', [
                'model' => $model,
                'modell' => $modell,
                ]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: update your question add  the ApplicantRatingScore model class  and tell use the fiedl/column name for the  'ApplicantRatingScore ID'

Comment: please show findModel()  function.